# Entity Core Framework Query is not correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to perform this Query and this is the result that I get from that:

```
SELECT dbo.Show.ShowId, dbo.Show.Name, dbo.Cast.CastId, dbo.Cast.Name, dbo.Cast.Birthday
FROM dbo.Show
INNER JOIN dbo.Cast ON dbo.Cast.ShowId = dbo.Show.ShowId
WHERE dbo.Cast.ShowId=1;
```

This is the output of this query
[image: Output of the query]

I am trying to write this query However this does not work

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetShowCast(long? showId)
        {
            var query = from s in db.Set<Show>()
                        join c in db.Set<Cast>()
                            on s.ShowId equals c.ShowId
                        where c.CastId == showId
                        select new { c.Birthday, s.Name};
            return Json(query);
        }
```

The database is working because this does work.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return Json(await db.shows.ToListAsync());
        }
```

What is wrong with my query?

What is wrong with my query?
I expect to receive this from query

After updating my query i still don't receive a result

```
       [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetShowCast(long? showId)
        {
            var query = from s in db.Set<Show>()
                        join c in db.Set<Cast>()
                            on s.ShowId equals c.ShowId
                        where s.ShowId == showId
                        select new { c.Birthday, s.Name };
            return Json(query.ToList());
        }
```

When i debug:
When debug this is see that `var result` is receiving nothing `Count = 0`

My models:

```
  [JsonProperty("id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public long CastId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("birthday")]
        public string? Birthday { get; set; }

        public long ShowId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Show> Show { get; set; }
```

Model Show

```
      [JsonProperty("id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public long ShowId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Cast> Casts { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the "not working" part? specifically, did you encounter error or given wrong output? also, what the query trying to do?

Comment: also, make sure the parameters are correct and of correct types.

Comment: You have a many-to-many relationship in your class model but it's one-to-many in the database. `Cast` should have a property `public Show Show { get; set; }` and you should use these *navigation properties* in your query. Remove the `join`. All answers so far lead you in the wrong direction. Your code can't work correctly as long as the class model and the database model have a mismatch. Fix that first.

Comment: That said, shouldn't there actually be a many-to-many relationship in the database, i.e. a junction table between `Show` and `Cast`? It seems that `Cast` is in fact an actor and I hope for actors that they can play in more than one show.

Answer (score 1):

There where multiple typo's that I made and `GetShowCast(long? showId)` should be `GetShowCast(long showId)`

The code bellow is working!

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetShowCast(long showId)
        {   
            var query = from s in db.Set<Show>()
                        join c in db.Set<Cast>()
                            on s.ShowId equals c.ShowId
                        where c.ShowId == 1
                        select new { c.Birthday, s.Name };

            var result = query.ToList();
            return Json(result);
        }
```

Comment: As hinted above, this should simply be `db.Set<Cast>().Where(...).Select(c => new { c.Birthday, c.Show.Name }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]//remove it
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetShowCast(long? showId)
        {
            var query = from s in db.Set<Show>()
                        join c in db.Set<Cast>()
                            on s.ShowId equals c.ShowId
                        where s.ShowId == showId
                        select new { c.Birthday, s.Name };
            return Json(query);
        }
```

Comment: When i debug:
When debug this is see that `var result` is receiving nothing `Count = 0`

Comment: @ozkan reyes
 Is  your CastId in your  Cast table? Do you want to get "1979" and "under the dome" ?

Comment: CastId is in my table indeed as you see in my SQL query. I want to receive all the columns in my table

Comment: @ozkan reyes
 I use your code, and I remove `[HttpGet("{id}")]`  and I  can get  "1979" and "under the dome" .You cannot get them?

Comment: [HttpGet("{id}")] is a rest needed for the rest api, however when i do  `where c.ShowId == 1` the query works indeed

Comment: @ozkan reyes so the problem is about you cannot get showId ?

Comment: Yes the cause was `long?` should have been `long` and the other feedback that I got

Comment: @ozkan reyes
 I just remove `[HttpGet("{id}")]`, and use GetShowCast(`long? showId`), the url is:https://localhost:7145/ControllerName/GetShowCast?showId=1  and I can get the result. You can try it.